# Is using a conditional statement based on this flag more efficient than adding more lines of code?

Tags: c++, sorting, conditional-statements, bubble-sort, flags

I have a sort function that accepts a Boolean parameter `desc` (descending) which sorts in reverse order if `true` & `algo` is an enum class that selects the algorithm (here the subset of the code is for `algo::BUBBLE` (bubblesort))

Using this inline conditional statement (`if (!desc ? A[j] > A[j + 1] : A[j] < A[j + 1])`), I can eliminate rewriting the entire code for reverse sort as it evaluates the appropriate condition based on the `desc` flag. But I wonder if this can create unnecessary overhead as it checks the flag repeatedly [*(n-1)*(1+2+...+n-1) times*]. Will this overhead come out as substantial for larger data elements? More code or more overhead?

```cpp
void Array<T>::sort(bool desc = false, algo a)
{

 if (algo == algo::BUBBLE)
 {
    bool wasSwapped = true;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size - 1 && wasSwapped; i++)
        {
            switched = false;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
            {
                if (!desc ? A[j] > A[j + 1] : A[j] < A[j + 1])
                {
                    wasSwapped = true;
                    swap(A[j], A[j + 1]);
                }
            }
        }
  }
}
```

`A` and `size` are private data members (Array pointer and size respectively).

Comment: If you are using bubble sort, it doesn't matter.  You could template specialize your first param if true to basically exit immediately though.

Comment: Ternary expressions (the conditional expression) tend to make code harder to read and understand,

Comment: Perhaps [benchmark](https://www.bfilipek.com/2016/01/micro-benchmarking-libraries-for-c.html) it to see if there's a difference? I/m guessing the CPU's branch prediction will make this negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For code clarity, it will be better to make that a non-member function template and pass it a compare functor. Make sure to put the function in your application's namespace so there is no confusion with the functions of the same name from the `std` namespace.

Assuming `Array<T>::A` is accessible,

```
namespace MyApp
{
   template <typename T, typename Compare = std::less<T>>
   void sort(Array<T>& array, algo a, Compare compare = Compare());
   {
      if (a == algo::BUBBLE)
      {
         bool wasSwapped = true;
         for (size_t i = 0; i < size - 1 && wasSwapped; i++)
         {
            switched = false;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
            {
               if (!compare(array.A[j], array.A[j + 1]))
               {
                  wasSwapped = true;
                  swap(array.A[j], array.A[j + 1]);
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now you can use:

```
Array<int> a = { ... };
MyApp::sort(a, algo::BUBBLE);                      // std::less<int> is the default functor.
MyApp::sort(a, algo::BUBBLE, std::greater<int>()); // Explicit compare functor.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are really worried about this extra check, you might create the implementation function as a template one with comparator provided as a template argument (similar to `std::sort`).

Than you will call the implementation function from your main one with either greater than or smaller than as a comparator depending on boolean flag.

Answer (score 1):

*But I wonder if this can create unnecessary overhead as it checks the flag repeatedly [(n-1)*(1+2+...+n-1) times*

No it will not. The compiler sees where each variable is written and read. It will adjust accordingly.

And, in any case, in your example, performance will be limited by reading and writing the array. As bubble-sort goes, you'll be doing way more reads and writes than needed. Compare it on a large array (million entries) with the code as is, and a hard-coded descending search. By bet is on the timings being identical.